# How to import external files?

Tags: solidity, evm

I'm trying to create a `fund` function that allows users to fund their wallet after signing. I had my contract address & ABI stored in an external file and tried to export and import, but that didn't work. Please note: I'm a newbie. If what I'm saying doesn't make sense,here is a picture:

[image]

After connecting and funding my contract, this is what my code results in:

```
Dapp.js:35 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Cannot access 'contractAddress' before initialization
    at fundMe (Dapp.js:35:53)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (Dapp.js:13:5)
```

Comment: Consider providing the `Dapp.js` code directly into your question body as opposed to a screenshot, this will help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your `Dapp.js` code I can't be entirely sure of what the issue is, but based on what I can see, it seems like you are trying to declare a variable using the same name as an already existing variable.

```js
const contractAddress = new ethers.contract(contractAddress, abi)
```

Instead of declaring the contract variable `contractAddress`, try renaming it:

```js
const myContract = new ethers.contract(contractAddress, abi)
```

This way you aren't shadowing your imported variable with the same name.

Comment: Thanks alot, this was also what i did thanks for assisting me.

Comment: @SABER No problem glad to help! Make sure to mark the answer as `accepted` using the little green checkmark when you get a chance to show that your problem was solved